# 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd CSV file 1/2 Char

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, unicode

I am reading a CSV file, via a Django upload file control.

I want to store `½` (1/2) into the database, but it gives the following exception:

```
  'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd C.S.V. file 1/2 Char
UnicodeDecodeError at /admin/request_system/customers/upload/
```

'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbd in position 45: invalid start byte

Comment: Can you show us the code for the Django view? How are you reading the CSV file?

Comment: Are you sure it is utf-8 encoded?

Comment: with open(Customer.get_temp_file_name(), 'r') as data_file:
                reader = MyFileReader(_file=data_file)


 def __init__(self, _file=None):
        if _file:
            self.DATA_FILE = csv.DictReader(_file)

Comment: well i am not sure, if its utf-8, cuz i have tried every thing to convert 1/2, nothing is working

Comment: @Cannon: you can [edit] your question to add detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your CSV file is not in utf8 format, so the decoder is seeing an invalid (i.e., non-utf8) byte sequence. Figure out the correct format and/or re-save the CSV file as utf8, then upload again.

`0xbd` is the ½ character in Latin-1, so that's most likely what you've got now. utf8 represents it as the two-byte sequence `\xc2\xbd`.

Comment: Perfect, i think this is the easier way. just to convert the csv file into UTF-8 and upload again. the 1/2 char have been saved correctly. 

Thanks +1

Comment: You are welcome. Please "accept" my answer (click on the bick check mark) if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong character set, probably Windows-1252. It's not Unicode or utf-8.

```
s = s.decode('windows-1252')
```

Comment: If django is expecting utf8, the simplest thing is to give it utf8.

Comment: @alexis, based on the error message it's already doing a `decode`. I'll bet it skips that if it's already given Unicode.

Comment: @MarkRansom: web uploads are always bytestreams, to get unicode it'll have to decode. You cannot receive Unicode from a web request. Or are you claiming that UTF8 is Unicode; it's an encoding, not the standard or a Python unicode value.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, if that's the case then why is it trying to do a `decode` in the first place? I admit I don't know much about Django.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Why not? Why would you manipulate date strings when you can manipulate datetime objects instead? Why would you manipulate digits in a string if you could have numbers? Decoding to unicode at the boundaries makes sense when handling text.